# Docker - Apache HTTP Proxy - Dynamic servername

Tags: apache, docker, proxy

I currently deploy a set of services in containers, one of which is an apache server that serves as a proxy between the client and an application server.

My issue is that if the ServerName directive does not exactly match the name of the Server that the user is navigating to, apache does nothing with the request. Currently it is hardcoded.

For example:

User A navigates to: https://myapp.example.com/

My Apache config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    UseCanonicalName On
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ServerName myapp.example.com

    ProxyPass           /   http://application:3000/ keepalive=On retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://application:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

I want the 'ServerName' directive to be dynamic and not hardcoded. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) would be a better place to ask about Apache HTTP config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding server alias

```
ServerAlias *.com
```

afrer ServerName directive.

Comment: Should the ServerName directive follow the same format? i.e ServerName *.com
ServerAlias *.com

Again, I dont want to hardcode. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryce It should work without * in ServerName. Not sure that wildcard chars in ServerName are allowed. You could also use the fact that it will default to 
first vhost entry if match wasn't found

Comment: I'm glad it did :)